# Add side-bar in JHipster application

Tags: jhipster

I want to insert a sidebar into the body of the element body in a JHipster application.

Is there a command that can help me?

Comment: No it's up to you  to code it manually. Don't forget that JHipster is not a framework, it's a code generator that you must customize.

Comment: But i think that there is a module that can generate it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no module available for converting JHipster's nav bar into a sidebar.  JHipster generates the code, but you will need to customize it yourself depending on your requirements.

You can see available JHipster commands by running `jhipster --help`, and the command's options by running `jhipster service --help` (example showing the `service` subgenerator options).

JHispter also offers modules, which extend JHipster's functionality with new commands. The full list can be viewed in the [JHipster Module Marketplace](http://www.jhipster.tech/modules/marketplace/#/list).  No module offers a sidebar option at this point in time.